# How to create a PriorityQueue with new comparator and NO specified initial capacity?

Tags: java, priority-queue

in Java, I don't know how to create a new `PriorityQueue` with new comparator but without given the queue length? How can I create it?

I know I can write:

```
Queue<Node> theQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(15,new Comparator<Node>();
```

But I hope the queue can works like `LinkedList`, I mean its length is not fixed, how can I declare it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern answer, as of 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30015986/139010

---

Pre-Java-8 answer, for posterity:

There is no such constructor. As per the JavaDocs, [the default capacity is 11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28%29), so you could specify that for analogous behavior to the no-arg `PriorityQueue` constructor:

```
Queue<Node> theQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(11,new Comparator<Node>());
```

And yes, [the queue will grow if it needs to.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> A priority queue is unbounded, but has an internal capacity governing the size of an array used to store the elements on the queue. It is always at least as large as the queue size. As elements are added to a priority queue, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified.x

Comment: Got it. And another question: if I want to do local beam search, I need to limit the PriorityQueue to a fix number (for example: 10), how can I fix the length of a PriorityQueue?

Comment: Use a size-bounded [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Comment: But the LinkedBlockingQueue class works differently from PriorityQueue, right? Can a queue have the feature of both LinkedBlockingQueue and PriorityQueue?

Comment: Java 8 offers a constructor to do what is asked in the question.

Comment: @NaveenKumar thanks for the info. Do you mind posting a link to the JavaDocs for this?

Comment: @MattBall Sure. Here it is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-
Joris Kinable has already added it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30015986/6038386

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my answer to point to Joris' as the more-relevant one.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Java version 8 there's a new constructor which can do what you ask for: PriorityQueue(Comparator comparator)

So you would get:

```
Queue<Node> theQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>());
```

Comment: From doc: `Creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity and whose elements are ordered according to the specified comparator.` So, it still 11 xD

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid theres no way to specify only a `Comparator` without specifying an initial capacity.  Note that this is only the initial capacity - the queue can grow from this initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a priority queue with self-defined comparator without fixing the size by using Java Lambda, a feature in Java SE 8.

For example, you can do:

`PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2));`

See example about Lambda: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/